# when click in EditText numberpad comes with footer layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, numpad

I have made a simple android activity with some edit texts and some TextVies and "header" and "footer" layouts,Now all is working well,but at runtime ,when i click on any on EditText the numberpad popups and comes with my "footer" layout.I have put my activity image below so that you can get my problem,My code is as below:

**main.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:padding="3dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="General Details"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/back1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Back" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Next1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="Next" />

        </RelativeLayout>
         <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

            <ScrollView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:layout_weight="0.23" android:fillViewport="true">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="509dp"
                    android:background="#fffff3"
                    android:padding="10dp" >


                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc2"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                         android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:imeOptions="actionNext">

                    </EditText>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc1"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButtonCalcTip2"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc1"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc2"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:enabled="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:focusable="false"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc3"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc3"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"
                        android:typeface="serif" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc3"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc4"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc4"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc4"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc5"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc5"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc6"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc6"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc7"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:enabled="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:focusable="false"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/buttonPropertyCalcClear"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/togglebutton"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="Clear All" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc1"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc1"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
                        android:text="Purchase Price"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse"
                        android:typeface="serif" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc2"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButtonCalcTip2"
                        android:text="Refurnishment Cost"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse"
                        android:typeface="serif" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc3"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc3"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
                        android:text="Legal Cost"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse"
                        android:typeface="serif" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc4"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc4"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
                        android:text="Mortage Loan to Value(LTV)% "
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse"
                        android:typeface="serif" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc5"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc5"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView02"
                        android:text="Mortage Interest Rate %"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse"
                        android:typeface="serif" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView05"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc6"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc6"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:text="Monthly Rent"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse"
                        android:typeface="serif" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView06"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc7"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc7"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:text="Letting Agent Fees"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse"
                        android:typeface="serif" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView07"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc8"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView06"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView04"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButtonCalcTip7"
                        android:text="Montlhly Operating Expenses %"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse"
                        android:typeface="serif" />

                     <TextView
                         android:id="@+id/TextView8"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                         android:layout_marginTop="390dp"
                         android:layout_marginRight="180dp"            
                         android:text="Will you be borrowing any of the deposit money?"
                         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse"
                         android:typeface="serif" />

                        />




                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButtonCalcTip1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc1"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc1"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView02"
                        android:background="#0000"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButtonCalcTip2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc2"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc2"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView02"
                        android:background="#0000"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButtonCalcTip3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc3"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc3"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView02"
                        android:background="#0000"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButtonCalcTip4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc4"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc4"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView02"
                        android:background="#0000"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButtonCalcTip5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc5"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc5"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView02"
                        android:background="#0000"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButtonCalcTip7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc7"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc7"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView02"
                        android:background="#0000"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButtonCalcTip8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc8"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc8"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView02"
                        android:background="#0000"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/buttonMortgageAmount"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc3"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc3"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc3"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc3" android:background="#0000"/>

                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/togglebutton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextPropertyCalc3"
                        android:textOff="No"
                        android:textOn="Yes" />

                </RelativeLayout>

    **</ScrollView>** 

   <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_grey" >

                <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButtonHome"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/g3570" android:layout_weight="0.6" android:background="#0000" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

                <TextView                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                     android:text="Home"
                    android:gravity="center" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse" android:textColor="#fff" android:textStyle="bold"/>

                </LinearLayout> <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButtonTraining"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/g4404" android:layout_weight="0.6" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:background="#0000" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
                    <TextView                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                     android:text="Training"
                    android:gravity="center" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse" android:textColor="#fff" android:textStyle="bold"/>

                </LinearLayout> <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButtonContactUs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_email" android:layout_weight="0.6" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:background="#0000" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
                   <TextView                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                     android:text="Contact Us"
                    android:gravity="center" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse" android:textColor="#fff" android:textStyle="bold"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

My image of Activity is as below:

[image]

Please help me for my this error .thank you friends.

Comment: i could't find where is your ScrollView closed in after footer finish

Comment: @altaf-i have edited my code and bold the "</scrollView> tag.now tell me

Comment: what you have done??? Scrollview close after footer layout..??
?

Comment: @altaf-no...<scrollView> closed before footerlayout..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code this is worked for me...

```
  public class Calculator extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calculator);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

}
}
```

Comment: getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); this is a solution for your issue..

Answer (score 0):

Use this code below this will help you...

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

 or Use this code

 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity android:name=".Main"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
          >
```

Comment: you put this code in to your java file inside anywhere in onCreate Method or your manifest..

Comment: still not working my friend..!can you please tell me ,any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late

In my case, I have added these lines of code below in the Oncreate function and top of the Layout

like below

[image]

code is here:

```
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```